# Error while installing boost and PyUblas on mac os x

Tags: c++, python, macos, boost

I have installed boost_1_55 using macport with the following command 
"sudo port install boost"
no errors.
I am now trying to install PyUblas on my mac but i keep getting the following error

> ```
> > src/wrapper/main.cpp:16:10: fatal error: 'boost/python.hpp' file not
> > found
>
> #include <boost/python.hpp>
> 1 error generated.
> error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
> ```

can anyone help?

Comment: Thanks Damien, I was trying to figure out how to get it to look like that.

Answer (score 1):

Installing boost from packages (Macports, Brew, etc) did not work for me, but installing from source did.

Download source from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/

`cd` into folder, then install with:

```
./bootstrap.sh 
./b2
./b2 install
```